# Powershell is trying to use python from a directory which doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

I'm currently trying to use OpenCV to detect colors in a Video, however when I try to execute the file using the Windows Power Shell it says:

```
No Python at 'c:\python 37\python37-32\python.exe'
```

But this directory doesn't exist. I looked at my Path variables, but it isn't one of them.

I'd be glad if any of you could help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a PowerShell error message - who's emitting that error? What do you mean by "when I try to execute the file"? What file, and how are you executing it?

Comment: Isn't python library directories in `%AppData%`, `Program Files`, or `Program Files(x86)`? Also `python.exe` is in either `c:\Windows` or `c:\Windows\System32`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to identify "python" at the environment variables

[this link](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/) will walk you through it:

Summary:

- Start the Run box and enter sysdm.cpl:
- Go to the Advanced tab and click the Environment Variables
- In the System variable window, find the Path variable and click Edit
- Position your cursor at the end of the Variable value line and add the path to the python.exe file, preceeded with the semicolon character (;). In our example, we have added the following value: ;C:\Python34
- Close all windows. Now you can run python.exe without specifying the full path to the file

Wish this helps ^^